# How to compare the input of two columns in the same table to validate data input?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to compare the text input for each row between two columns in the same table

This is my dax formula that I use:

```
Checkpoint = IF(AND(CONTAINSROW('tweedelijns melding'[Korte omschrijving (Details)], "ADW", "Wachtwoord","reset","Resetten", "Uitvraagscript", "Profile","Citrix", "Aanvraag") && 'tweedelijns melding'[Object ID] = "Active directory" ||'tweedelijns melding'[Object ID] = "Citrix"), "Match", "No match")
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

The [Korte omschrijving (Details)] column contains a question and the object ID contains mostly one or two words.

I would like to check whether the column [Korte omschrijving (Details)] contains words like "ADW", "Wachtwoord","reset","Resetten" ..... and if the column [object ID] contain words such as "Active directory" or "Citrix" if so, then it will count as a match otherwise not.

This is the output that it should generates:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr5t8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Power Query approach that seems to work.

Starting with your table as Table1:

[image]

I added a custom column:

[image]

Here's the M code for the custom column formula:

```
if List.ContainsAny(
    Text.Split(Text.Upper([Question])," "),
    List.Transform({"ADW", "Wachtwoord","reset","Resetten", "Uitvraagscript", "Profile","Citrix", "Aanvraag"}, each Text.Upper(_))
) 
    then if List.ContainsAny(
        Text.Split(Text.Upper([Categorie]),""),
        List.Transform({"Active directory", "citrix"}, each Text.Upper(_))
    ) 
    then "match" 
    else "no match" 
else "no match"
```

What it does is it splits each of the Question column's row into a list of its words, then compares that list with a list of your words, {"ADW", "Wachtwoord","reset","Resetten", "Uitvraagscript", "Profile","Citrix", "Aanvraag"}, to see if any of the words in your list of words are in that list created from the Question row. If there is a match, then it does the same with the Categorie column. But...for the Categorie column, it really only makes a one item list for each row. In other words... As an example, "Verzoek resetten wachtwoord", from Question becomes the list {"VERZOEK", "RESETTEN", "WACHTWOORD"} and "Active Directory", from Categorie becomes the list {"ACTIVE DIRECTORY"}. If there is a match in both lists, then "match" is returned. Otherwise, "no match" is returned.

The Text.Split is what converts to the list. The List.ContainsAny is what compares the list contents. I used Text.Upper to force the Question Categorie info to uppercase and I used List.Transform to force the lists of your words to uppercase, to ensure appropriate comparison for matching.

Here's my result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! it wokred just fine. :)

Comment: could you maybe take a look at this post?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/60617568/12912886