# Matching rows between two columns to get an exact or partial match

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I’m having a problem writing a query in power bi for matching two rows partially or completely. In addition to that I’m trying to calculate the match percentage if found and put the results in a new column.

The actual dataset contains a lot of rows and tables but for the sake of this example I’m using only 4 columns.

The columns 'ID' and 'Text' are uniquely identified. 'KI ID' and 'KI Test' are also unique but they are not related to columns 'ID' and 'Text' only when a match occurs.

**What I need to implement is the following:**

I would like to match the input of each row in the 'Text' column with each row in the 'KI text' column. If there is a match, then I would like to know the 'KI ID’ and the Match percentage. Take a look at the data set for a better insight.

**ps:** Is this actually achievable with power query or is it just a fantasy because in my perspective I’m heading towards machine learning, I think?

Data set
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JrsxPa6DICNi5N-tI5ESukh62W_uedaQ

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTXn4.png)

The match calculation is based on the amount of words that occurs in both columns, 'Text' and 'KI Text'. for example, if one of the rows in the 'Text' column contains two sentences and these sentences partially matches with one of the 'KI Text' rows which has like 6 sentences in total. The match between the rows is partially so basically it should calculate it as 2/6 so it's like 33,3% match.

In addition, the 'KI Text' column contains a lot of rows that could passably match with one of the ‘Text' column rows. Only if it's greater or equals to 80% then it should show the results otherwise it’s not interesting.

Comment: Did you mention somewhere how you calculate the match percentage?

Comment: Hmmm, you are right I didn't describe this very clearly, the match calculation is based on the amount of words that occurs in both columns, 'Text' and 'KI Text'. for example, if one of the rows in the 'Text' column contains two sentences and these sentences partially matches with one of the 'KI Text' rows which has like 6 sentences in total. The match between the rows is partially so basically it should calculate it as 2/6 so it's like 33,3% match.

Comment: In addition, the 'KI Text' column contains a lot of rows that could passably match with one of the ‘Text' column rows. Only if it's greater or equals to 80% then it should show the results otherwise it’s not interesting.

Great question btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, this is what you're looking for, or at least brings you closer to an answer.

While I believe your ID / Text and KI ID / KI Text data most likely come from two different tables, you presented them in one spreadsheet as your [data set](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JrsxPa6DICNi5N-tI5ESukh62W_uedaQ), so I started with that. The only content available to me in your spreadsheet was Sheet2. I simply copied and pasted the contents of your spreadsheet's Sheet2 to my own spreadsheet in Excel. I then used the default table name of Table1 to refer to it. I brought it in just like you presented it:

[image]

Then, still working within the same query, I separated it into two new tables: an ID table and a KI ID table. You can make the first table by selecting the existing ID and Text columns, then Home > Remove Columns > Remove Other Columns; but to make the second table, you would need to use the formula bar.

[image]

Before I made the second table, I added a column to the first table (the ID table) with the number 1 in every row. I called that column ID Match Key.

[image]

Then I copied the first table's formula from the applied step where I had created it, to use it in the formula bar to create the second table for KI ID. I edited it, changing the column's names as appropriate for KI ID:

[image]

Then I added a column with the number 1 in every row to the second table (the KI ID table). I called that column KI ID Match Key.

[image]

Then I did a full outer merge of the two tables that I had just made--the ID and KI ID tables. To do this, I first used Home > Merge Queries and merged Table1 with itself. (Which column to use for a match doesn't matter, because this is temporary.) I selected Full Outer as the Join Kind. Once the merge was done, I edited the merge in the formula bar, to change the tables to #"Added ID Match Key" and #"Added KI ID Match Key" (which happen to be the names of the those two "tables" after I created them and added their match keys to use in this merge) and the respective matching fields to "ID Match Key" and "KI ID Match Key":

[image]

After the merge, I expanded the resultant column:

[image]

Then I replaced all nulls in both the Text and KI Text columns with blank text by selecting both columns (by clicking one column, then clicking and holding Ctrl) then clicking Transform > Replace Values > typing null in the "Value To Find" box and leaving the "Replace With" box blank, and clicking OK.

Then I added columns to split each of the Text and KI Text columns cells into lists of their words. Before I did each split though, I first filtered out everything except lowercase and capital text a through z, numbers 0 through 9, spaces, and equal signs. I used Text.SplitAny to split the words at any spaces or equals signs:

[image]

[image]

Then I added a column and determined what words from Text were in KI Text. I used List.Intersect to do that. It lists the duplicates, which is something I wanted:

[image]

Then I added a column and did the reverse--determined what words from KI Text were in Text. Again, I used List.Intersect:

[image]

Then I collected count information. I created a new column with the count of the number of words (all occurrences) in each of the lists I had created. I did this once each for Text, KI Text, Text in KI Text, and KI Text in Text. I simply used List.Count to do this. This wasn't actually necessary to do as separate steps with separate columns. I just did it to clearly see the numbers. The M code I generated in the two columns that follow these four columns doesn't use these four columns. I did the counting in those next two columns as well:

[image]

Next, I created two new columns to calculate the % of Text in KI Text and the % of KI Text in Text. I used these basic formulas (presented here in, hopefully, clear english, versus the M code):

- % Text in KI Text = (Number of words from Text that are in KI Text /
  Number of words in KI Text) * 100
- % KI Text in Text = (Number of
  words from KI Text that are in Text / Number of words in Text) * 100

  *Be sure to check my math.*

[image]

Last, I removed all the columns I no longer wanted.

[image]

**After your initial three comments, I added some steps to my query to get this:**

[image]

Here's the M code *with the edits that I made after your three comments*. See my comments for more context.:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", type text}, {"Text", type text}, {"KI ID", type text}, {"KI Text", type text}, {"Outcome", type text}}),
    #"Made ID Table" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"ID", "Text"}),
    #"Added ID Match Key" = Table.AddColumn(#"Made ID Table", "ID Match Key", each 1),
    #"Made KI ID Table" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"KI ID", "KI Text"}),
    #"Added KI ID Match Key" = Table.AddColumn(#"Made KI ID Table", "KI ID Match Key", each 1),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added ID Match Key", {"ID Match Key"}, #"Added KI ID Match Key", {"KI ID Match Key"}, "KI Table", JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Expanded KI Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "KI Table", {"KI ID Match Key", "KI ID", "KI Text"}, {"KI ID Match Key", "KI ID", "KI Text"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded KI Table",null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Text", "KI Text"}),
    #"Split Text to List" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Text Listed", each Text.SplitAny(Text.Select([Text],{"a".."z","A".."Z","0".."9"," ","="})," =")),
    #"Split KI Text to List" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split Text to List", "KI Text Listed", each Text.SplitAny(Text.Select([KI Text],{"a".."z","A".."Z","0".."9"," ","="})," =")),
    #"Got Text in KI Text" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split KI Text to List", "Text in KI Text", each List.Intersect({[KI Text Listed],[Text Listed]})),
    #"Got KI Text in Text" = Table.AddColumn(#"Got Text in KI Text", "KI Text in Text", each List.Intersect({[Text Listed], [KI Text Listed]})),
    //You don't actually need the next four lines. I included them so you can see the numbers in the table. They are calculated in the two #"Calculated..." lines below.
    //If you choose to remove them, you'll need to replace #"Got Count of KI Text in Text", in the first #"Calculated..." line, with #"Got KI Text in Text".
    #"Got Count of Text" = Table.AddColumn(#"Got KI Text in Text", "Text Count", each List.Count([Text Listed])),
    #"Got Count of KI Text" = Table.AddColumn(#"Got Count of Text", "KI Text Count", each List.Count([KI Text Listed])),
    #"Got Count of Text in KI Text" = Table.AddColumn(#"Got Count of KI Text", "Text in KI Text Count", each List.Count([Text in KI Text])),
    #"Got Count of KI Text in Text" = Table.AddColumn(#"Got Count of Text in KI Text", "KI Text in Text Count", each List.Count([KI Text in Text])),
    #"Calculated % Text in KI Text" = Table.AddColumn(#"Got Count of KI Text in Text", " % Text in KI Text", each Number.Round((List.Count([Text in KI Text])/List.Count([KI Text Listed]))*100, 2), type number),
    #"Calculated % KI Text in Text" = Table.AddColumn(#"Calculated % Text in KI Text", "% KI Text in Text", each Number.Round((List.Count([KI Text in Text])/List.Count([Text Listed]))*100, 2), type number),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Calculated % KI Text in Text",{"ID", "Text", "KI ID", "KI Text", " % Text in KI Text", "% KI Text in Text"}),
    //
    //What follows is my edit after your three comments.
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Outcome", each Text.From([#" % Text in KI Text"]) & "% match with " & [KI ID]),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"ID"}, {{"AllData", each _, type table [ID=text, Text=text, KI ID=text, KI Text=text, #" % Text in KI Text"=number, #"% KI Text in Text"=number, Outcome=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Text", each [AllData][Text]{0}),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Outcome", each [AllData][Outcome]),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom2", {"Outcome", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "#(cr)"), type text}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"ID", "Text", "Outcome"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns1"
```

Comment: Hi Marc

First of all, thank you very much for your time. I’m definitely closer to the desired result thanks to you.

I’m trying to understand the following steps:

1-Then I added a column and determined what words from Text were in KI Text. I used List.Intersect to do that. It lists the duplicates, which is something I wanted:

2-Then I added a column and did the reverse--determined what words from KI Text were in Text. Again, I used List.Intersect:

Why do you intersect both ways?  is it just more accurate?

Comment: Another question that I have is as you already know, ‘KI ID’ and ’KI Text’ are uniquely related to each other. So is it possible to display which one of the ‘KI ID’ that are shown in the column has intersected with the ‘Text’ column  because only if the intersect % higher or equals to 80% then it should say like “ 80% match with KI 1314”  as shown in the ‘Output’ column in my spreadsheet.

Comment: Important note: The Match between ‘ Text’ and ‘KI Text’ happens in random order so it doesn’t has to be horizontally (on the same row) but it could also happen in different row’s like the letter X

Comment: For your first comment, I wasn't certain whether I would miss any matches if I only compared the text from one direction, so I did if from both to be sure. It appears it would only require comparison from one direction though. (I learned something.)  For your second comment, yes: to see a statement for what percent of ID matches KI ID add a new column with `Text.From([#" % Text in KI Text"]) & "% match with " & [KI ID]`. To only provide the statement for >80% matches, use `if [#" % Text in KI Text"] >= 80 then Text.From([#" % Text in KI Text"]) & "% match with " & [KI ID] else null`.

Comment: For your third comment, this query takes the first ID and compares it against each KI ID. It compares every ID against every KI ID. You'll see that it duplicated the KI IDs so that they repeat once for each ID--each KI ID appears in a row with each ID. Then the ID in each row compares with the KI ID in its row. Later, you can use Group By and/or other filtering to portray the table however you may wish. I presented one possibility as an edit to my earlier post. You'll see a new screen clip and new M code.

Comment: Thanks again, I have reconstructed my data model and i'm trying to reproduce your steps. However you didn't use a formula to the following step, correct me if i'm wrong:

"Then I added columns to split each of the Text and KI Text columns cells into lists of their words."

The following formula comes after you split the column cells into lists of their words right? 

Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Text Listed", each Text.SplitAny(Text.Select([Text],{"a".."z","A".."Z","0".."9"," "," ="})," ="))

Comment: No. That formula is how I split them. It's a compound formula. First, it uses Text.Select to remove everything except the text, numbers, commas, and equal signs from [Text], then it uses Text.SplitAny to split [Text] any time it encounters a space or equal sign. Text.SplitAny is what actually makes the list. You probably already saw this, but to be sure...for [KI Text], I replaced [Text] with [KI Text].)

Comment: The listed formula is not working for me, maybe because I have a relational model....however i don't think that this is the main reason. drive.google.com/open?id=1oLjnA0VYJXAVhpYmuuFVtKBqTC70cP0w This picture shows you that i'm getting a table instead of a list, when opening the table I do see a new column "Text" but it shows an error instead of a list :(  
so am I doing somthing wrong??

Comment: I don't know how you wound up with the nested table or adding the column to that nested table because I don't have enough of your code. Text.SplitAny would not do that, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-splitany). It simply creates a list from text.

Comment: I have figured it out using your M code, however i'm running into some math problems regarding the match percentages, its pretty low and way below my expectations i'm getting like between 10 and 35 % match, by matching  the % text in KI Text only.
Do you have any tips how i can improve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't.